# Using Vue $refs dynamically inside of function with parameter

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, vue.js, ref

I am trying to access a DOM element with Vue, using the `$refs` functionality, but I am having trouble getting it to work.

My element looks like so below. The plateId is generated dynamically, so it will not always be the same number:

```
<textarea :ref="plateId + '-notes'">
```

My Vue function looks like so:

```
/* This does not work */
addNotes: function(plateId) {
    console.log(this.$refs.plateId + '-notes');
}
```

Whenever I run this code and the function is activated, it just reads `undefined` in my console. I've also tried this, which also does not work and reads undefined:

```
/* This does not work */
addNotes: function(plateId) {
    var plateIdNotes = plateId + '-notes';
    console.log(this.$refs.plateIdNotes);
}
```

Replacing `var` with `const` (I am using ES6 and transpiling the code) doesn't work either:

```
/* This does not work */
addNotes: function(plateId) {
    const plateIdNotes = plateId + '-notes';
    console.log(this.$refs.plateIdNotes);
}
```

I know the `ref` is binding correctly to the element, because when I do this below, I can see all of my other refs in the console, as well as the plateId-notes ref:

```
/* This works */
addNotes: function(plateId) {
    console.log(this.$refs);
}
```

How can I access the `plateId` ref using the parameter in my function?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can use the `[]` notation:

```
  methods: {
    foo (id) {
        alert(this.$refs[id + '-test'].innerText)
    }
  }
```

A complete working example: https://jsfiddle.net/drufjsv3/2/

Comment: adding to this, if you are using this inside a bunch of components made using `v-for` with dynamic `refs`, you will need to use `this.$refs[id + '-test'][0].innerText` to access anything in that component

https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref

Answer (score 1):

also, you can acces to all the $refs rendered in view by accessing

```
vm.$children.forEach( child => {
    var tag = child.$vnode.data.ref;
    console.log(vm.$refs[tag]);
    vm.$refs[tag].loadData();  
});
// loadData() is a method to implement when mounted or when you want to reload data
```

////////////////////////////////////

```
<script>
    export default {

      data() {
        return {
            notifications: []
        }
    },

    mounted() {
        this.loadData();
    },

    methods: {

        loadData: function() {
            axios.get('/request-json/notifications').then(res => {
                this.notifications = res.data;
            });
        },
.....
```